# How to import StreamingResponseBody in spring mvc project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to import it from "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody". But it is showing me an error that the import cannot be resolved.

Actually I am using it as the equivalent class of StreamingOutput Class in java to loop through very large set of data using hibernate.

For further reference u can see the below link:

http://mitchdickinson.com/exporting-very-large-data-sets-with-hibernate-jax-rs/

Comment: I think you need Spring Web MVC in your classpath. If you use maven just add the dependency to your pom. If not put it manually in your classpath.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi -Hi, I have already injected the maven dependency in my pom.xml file for spring-webmvc and i am using 4.0.1 release version for spring. Is This the issue ? Can you please help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add spring-mvc as dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The class `StreamingResponseBody` is introduced in [Spring 4.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html)

You can use the version - [4.3.7.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.7.RELEASE) in maven pom.xml file